# float object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, integer

```
# Convert array to float and rescale to voltage.
# Assume 3.3V / 12bits
# (we need calibration data to do a better job on this)
data = data.astype(np.float32) * (3.3 / 2**12)
if downsample > 1:  # if downsampling is requested, average N samples together
    data = data.reshape(num/downsample,downsample).mean(axis=1)
    num = data.shape[0]
    return np.linspace(0, (num-1)*1e-6*downsample, num), data, rate
else:
    return np.linspace(0, (num-1)*1e-6, num), data, rate`
```

In this part: `data = data.reshape(num/downsample,downsample).mean(axis=1)`, I'm getting this error:

```
float object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` sign in Python3 equates to floating point division or "true" division. So the result will always be a float.

There are two ways you can fix this. However, you should first make sure that your data can be cleanly divided (without a decimal portion) into `num*downsample` or this will still cause an error:

```
data = data.reshape(num//downsample,downsample).mean(axis=1)
```

or:

```
data = data.reshape(int(num/downsample),downsample).mean(axis=1)
```

Both versions get the floored version of the resulting number. So you want to be sure that the number acquired through `num/downsample` is something like "x.0" for `reshape` to not complain.